# SSRS: Find value in Stored procedure dataset to determine which graphic to display

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, lookup

its probably been answered somewhere before but i am having no luck with what i am trying to do.

The set up is i have a dataset in SSRS (2015) from a stored procedure in SQL. Sample data:

[image]

I am trying to use the results of that table to determine which graphic is displayed. The graphic is currently held in a single cell table which is linked to the stored procedure in question. The sample code below is attached to the graphic in the table:

```
=Switch 
    (Lookup(Fields!DatasetLong.Value, "d", Fields!CountOnsite.Value, "SQLProc")>0,"Asset2600x",
     Lookup(Fields!DatasetLong.Value, "d", Fields!Count_0_50m.Value, "SQLProc")>0,"Asset7600x",
     Lookup(Fields!DatasetLong.Value, "d", Fields!Count_50m_DataBuffer.Value, "SQLProc")>0,"Asset7600x",
     true, "Asset4600x"
     )
```

Note that the fields of Count* are stored are declared as Int.

Unfortuantely this is failing, i.e. I can deliberately change the argument to make a certain lookup fail but is still triggering or i can have it perfectly match the value its looking up and it will just skip that check.

Any ideas on best how to approach this? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unsure of how this is instended to work but I think you're using the Lookup incorrectly.

Currently it looks up field DatasetLong in the current dataset to match **d**. I think you want to search the Lookupset for **d**.

```
=Switch 
    (Lookup("d", Fields!DatasetLong.Value, Fields!CountOnsite.Value, "SQLProc") > 0,"Asset2600x",
     Lookup("d", Fields!DatasetLong.Value, Fields!Count_0_50m.Value, "SQLProc") > 0,"Asset7600x",
     Lookup("d", Fields!DatasetLong.Value, Fields!Count_50m_DataBuffer.Value, "SQLProc") > 0, "Asset7600x", 
     true, "Asset4600x"
     )
```

Comment: Legend, knew it was something simple like that